# Create expandable grid using material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a requirement to make expandable Grid i.e. when user click on row it should expand and show another grid below.

Do i need use custom Grid creation
Below is my code of rendering table

```
<TableBody>
  {tableData.length > 0 &&
    tableData.map((row, rowIndex) => {
      return (
        <React.Fragment key={`row-${rowIndex}`}>
          <TableRow>
              <TableCell key='column-checkbox'>
                Checkbox
              </TableCell>
            )}
            {row.columns.map((column, columnIndex) => {
              return (
                <TableCell
                  key={`column-${columnIndex}`}
                >
                  {column}
                </TableCell>
              )
            })}
          </TableRow>
        </React.Fragment>
      )
    })}
</TableBody>
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please, consider adding what you've tried so far. Consider editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add onCLick event on TableRow

```
handleRowCLick = () => {
//write code to render child table here
}
 <TableRow onClick={this.handleRowCLick}>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Thanks @Puneet for help, i will implement in this way